# Schur's Multiplier exercise (Problem 5A.7 Isaacs' Finite Group Theory)

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, cyclic-groups, transfer-theory

I have a question about the following problem [Finite Group Theory, Martin Isaacs, Chapter 5]:

*Let $ B $ and $ C $ be cyclic subgroups of a finite group G, and suppose that $ BC = G $ and $ B \cap C > 1 $. Assume that $ C \lhd G $ and that $ |C:G^{'}|=n $. Show that the order of $ M(G) $ is strictly less than $ n $.*

I report my reasoning:

For the third theorem of homomorphism, I know that $ B/B \cap C \cong BC/C=G/C $ and since $ B $ is cyclical, every quozient is also cyclical. So I'm in the hypothesis of the exercise 5A.5 from M.Isaacs Finite Group Theory and then I have to $ |M(G)| $ divides $ |C:G^{'}|=n $. Therefore $ |M(G)| $ is less than $ n $.

I can't justify the fact that it has to be **strictly** less than $ n $.  (I think it depends on the fact that $ C $ is a normal subgroup **proper** to $ G $).

Answer (score 4):

Let $\Gamma$ be a Schur representation group for $G$. So $\Gamma$ has a subgroup $Z \cong M(G)$ with $Z \le Z(\Gamma) \cap \Gamma'$ and $\Gamma/Z \cong G$.

Let $\bar{C}$ and $\bar{B}$ be the inverse images of the subgroups $C$ and $B$ of $G$ in $\Gamma$. So $\bar{B} \cap \bar{C}$ is the inverse image of $B \cap C$. Choose $\bar{b}\in\bar{B}$ and $\bar{c}\in\bar{C}$ as inverse images of generators of $C$ and $B$, so $\Gamma = \langle \bar{b},\bar{c},Z\rangle$. Then $\bar{B} \cap \bar{C}$ is centralized by $\bar{b}$, $\bar{c}$ and $Z$, so $\bar{B} \cap \bar{C} \le Z(\Gamma)$.

Note also that $\Gamma'$ is the inverse image of $G'$, so $|\bar{C}:\Gamma'| = |C:G'| = n$. Also $\bar{C}/Z \cong C$ is cyclic, so $\bar{C}$ is abelian.

Now we can apply Lemma 4.6 of Isaacs' book to the group $\Gamma$ with the abelian normal subgroup $\bar{C}$ of $\Gamma$. This tells us that $|\bar{C} \cap Z(\Gamma)| = |\bar{C}:\Gamma'| = n$. Since $\bar{B} \cap \bar{C} \le Z(\Gamma)$, and $Z$ is a proper subgroup of $\bar{B} \cap \bar{C}$, $|Z| =|M(G)|$ divides $n$ and is less than $n$.

Comment: Thank you. It's not clear why the order of M(G) is **strictly** less than n.

Comment: What does "strictly less than" mean? What is the difference between "strictly less than" and "less than"? I explained  in the final sentence that $Z$ is a PROPER subgroup of $\bar{B} \cap \bar{C}$. That means that the order of $Z$ is less than the order of  $\bar{B} \cap \bar{C}$, so the order of $Z$ is less than $n$.

Comment: Why is Z a proper subgroup of $ \overline{B} \cap \overline{C} $?

Comment: You are told that $B \cap C > 1$.